# Can't seem to connect to SQLServer 2008 express

Tags: sql-server, connection

I'm pretty new to this so i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong , I've downloaded SQLServer 2008 express and installed it but when i try to connect to PC-NAME\SQLEXPRESS i get Server not found error,
Do i need to install the server separately or is it suppose to be installed along with the sqlserver express?

Comment: So there are two pieces you are interested in. A client, usually ssms (sql server management studio) and the server, SQLServer. Both will need to be installed.

Comment: I take that back - if you're trying to connect from java you don't need the client, because java will be your client. You will need to make sure that the server is installed and running. Check under services that SQL Server([instance name]) exists and is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check services on whichever machine you think SQLServer Express is installed.

Make sure that SQL Server ( [instance name] ) exists and has a status of Started.
[image: Services]

Answer (score 1):

And make sure you trying to login with the right mode it is the mode you selected when you were installing the Sql Server (Windows Authentication/ Sql Server Authentication).
After you have made sure the SQLSERVER Services is running.